# How to get posts from a category using SQL query in Wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

I need to get posts from a category using SQL query in Wordpress, so i use get_resilts but it returns an empty array...please could someone tell me what is wrong in my code...? thanks a lot

```
$wpdb->get_results("
 SELECT ID, post_date 
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE    $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
   AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 18
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular need to use an SQL query with $wpdb?

This can be easily be achieved using WordPress functions:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'category' => 18 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

If using SQL is an absolute requirement you'll want to fix your query.

This is correct:

```
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
```

This is not:

```
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
```

Comment: thanks so i will add {$wpdb->prefix} in my query. Does get_posts return the same array as the SQL query ?

Comment: get_posts() returns an array of post objects: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

It'll provide all the same information, but you'll have to access it slightly differently.